# writing a gz stream with boost

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

I wrote a code to write the output to a `gz` file using `boost`.

```
class foo() {
  std::ofstream traceOut;
  struct traceRec {
    traceRec(uint64_t c) : cycle(c) {};
    uint64_t cycle;
  };
  void writeTrace(traceRec &rec)
  {
    try {
      boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
      in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
      in.push(traceOut);   // ERROR
      std::cout << rec.cycle << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const boost::iostreams::gzip_error& e) {
      std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
  }
  void init() {
    traceOut.open("log.gz", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
  }
  void bar() {
    traceRec rec (1000);
    writeTrace(rec);
  }
};
```

However I get this error while compiling

```
/opt/boost_1_33_1/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::iostreams::detail::chain_client<Chain>::push(std::basic_ostream<_CharT2,      _Traits2>&, int, int) [with CharType = char, TraitsType = std::char_traits<char>, Chain = boost::iostreams::chain<boost::iostreams::input, char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
test.cpp:   instantiated from here
/opt/boost_1_33_1/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp:472: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/opt/boost_1_33_1/boost/iostreams/traits.hpp: At global scope:
/opt/boost_1_33_1/boost/iostreams/traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::iostreams::detail::member_category<mpl_::void_>’:
/opt/boost_1_33_1/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::select<boost::iostreams::is_iostream<mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::iostream_tag, boost::iostreams::is_istream<mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::istream_tag, boost::iostreams::is_ostream<mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::ostream_tag, boost::iostreams::is_streambuf<mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::streambuf_tag, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::void_>, boost::iostreams::detail::member_category<mpl_::void_> >’
....
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html), the push() method must receive stream and not arbitrary objects

**EDIT1 (following comments exchange)**

Changing the type of `traceOut` to `std::ifstream` solves the build issue (at least using boost 1.52)

Comment: Doesn't `std::ofstream` qualify as a stream?

Comment: @mahmood Nope I didn't meant that :) according to boost static check it seems boost expecting their own iostream object and the std ofstream isn't an "acceptable" template so I vote using boost iostream object)

Comment: Also the combination of input and output streams could cause this hiccup (I wish boost doc was more verbose)

Comment: @mahmood as being good SO citizen :) can you accept my post ? since it clearly states your findings